# How to ensure that wi-fi is enabled or disabled using powershell?

Tags: powershell, wifi, powershell-2.0

We are using private network where ports are blocked by Firewall.

We will raise request to open ports for our machine IP address.

If wi-fi is enabled the system will have 2 IP address and if our connection routed through that IP address , we are unable to access our machines inside private network.

I would like to know whether any way is there in powershell to ensure the status (whether wi-fi is enabled/disabled).

Comment: I'd expect Windows to attempt to route requests through all available connections until it finds out if they can get through any of them, doesn't it work like this ?

Comment: @alex: When we turn off our wi-fi , we were able to connect to private network. So i think it doesn't route requests through all available connection.

Answer (score 3):

This one liner list all networkadapter matching wireless or wifi and that are enabled.

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapter -namespace root\CIMV2 | where-object {$_.Name -match "Wifi" -or $_.Name -match "wireless" -and $_.name -notmatch "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter" -and $_.netenabled -eq $true}   | select description, netenabled
```

this for disable:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapter -namespace root\CIMV2 | where-object {$_.Name -match "Wifi" -or $_.Name -match "wireless" -and $_.name -notmatch "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter" -and $_.netenabled -eq $true } | % { $_.disable() }
```

this for enable:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_networkadapter -namespace root\CIMV2 | where-object {$_.Name -match "Wifi" -or $_.Name -match "wireless" -and $_.name -notmatch "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter" -and $_.netenabled -eq $false } | % { $_.enable() }
```

Comment: `-match` is case insensitive so you don't need to check Wifi and wifi (cmatch is the case-sensitive version). You could also combine match items using `-match 'Wifi|wireless'`.

Comment: @AndyArismendi was a copy and paste error the W and w. I've edited my answer. The 'or' in regex is a good point! thank you

Comment: +1 It works for me (french operating system) except you are missing '}' before the last '|' in the enable/disable lines. I'am surprise that there no solution usin WMI associated class.

Comment: @JPBlanc .thankyou for catch the missing }! I've edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you fire up a command prompt you can get info about WLAN with this:

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

Redirect output into a `FIND` command and you should be good to go

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "turned off" /I /C
```

WARNING: My windows isn't en-* localized so I'm not sure about the "turned off" thing, you might want to launch the command without the `FIND` part, in order to see the message it returns and adjust accordingly (if you launch the `netsh` command you'll see for yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Or in case you need to know if wifi is connected from multiple remote machines you can list them in a file (in this case it is computers.txt) and run following script

```
$computers = Get-Content %PATH%\Computers.txt
$credentials = Get-Credential -Credential domain\username
     ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{
Write-Host "Computer Name: $computer"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {netsh wlan show interfaces} | select-string "State"
}
```